# WSL: emacs gui won't start

Tags: microsoft-windows, display, gui-emacs, ubuntu, wsl

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 10.0.21337 (windows insider program) and installed WSL with Ubuntu 20.04.
From within ubuntu I said

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install emacs
dpkg -l emacs
->
||/ Name           Version           Architecture Description
+++-==============-=================-============-=================================
ii  emacs          1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2 all          GNU Emacs editor (metapackage)
```

after installing I could launch emacs from the ubuntu bash and from the windows start menu.
It worked fine for a while but suddenly it crashed (I was measuring the effective keyboard delay rate in emacs by keeping the space bar pressed for up to 5 s, when it crashed, so I'm sure I didn't invoke anything special)
Since then, when I start it via the start menu nothing happens. It doesn't appear in the windows task manager but `ps auxww` lists a running process `/usr/bin/emacs` with 0% CPU.
When I start it on cmd line and press Ctrl-C it prints an unreadable character and then `Display :0 unavailable, simulating -nw`. (after the latest update it stopped printing that message).

I renamed my `.emacs` and `.emacs.d`, uninstalled and reinstalled it (including `apt autoremove`), with no success.

Then I tried command line options:
`emacs -Q` makes no difference.
`emacs --debug-init` prints nothing.
`emacs -nw` works: it starts the text version, so only the gui version is broken.

**UPDATE:**
I kept two emacs processes (one started from start menu, one from cmd line) running while putting the laptop through sleep + wakeup a couple of times. Once on waking up two emacs windows were visible! On the next wakeup they were invisible again. `ps` still shows the two processes. This means that it's indeed a window manager problem like @jue assumed or, say, a process manager problem. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: So probably not Emacs is broken, but some windows feature or service. `Display :0 unavailable` means Emacs Gui can not connect to the display server.  This could be due to a crashed display server or broken permissions. I do not know which window server Windos is using in conjunction with WSL. But surely you can google that.

Comment: Which xserver are you using? How is it configured? The following two tutorials helped me quite a bit:
- https://github.com/hubisan/emacs-wsl#changes-needed-for-wsl2
- https://elecming.medium.com/the-ultimate-emacs-hacking-tutorial-in-windows-10-wsl-2-cfd3ea3893e3